# Problem with tracking and adding files git

Tags: git, flask, heroku

Every time I try to add the file called "`api/environment/frontend/build/static/js/main.b6a36144.chunk.js.map`", which is a file generated after running npm run build, it keeps getting added to a different git repository in the path `/reminder-app`.

[image]

I want it to be added to the file called `api/environment` because I initialized a `git init` there already.

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Fyi, the path `/reminder-app` also has a `git init`.
I am building a frontend and backend files, and this is why I have separate git repositories.
I am deploying the files in api/environment to heroku.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> it keeps getting added to a different git repository in the path `/reminder-app`.
> I want it to be added to the file called `api/environment` because I initialized a `git init` there already.

Not sure which "different repository" you are referring to, but make sure you don't have any additional .git folder in `reminder-app/` subfolders (beside `/reminder-app/.git` itself): a nested folder would not displayed any added file in it.

If you have two repositories, one should not be within the other, but in two separate folders.